# Did Adi Shankaracharya make an argument for a perfect God (Brahman) against Buddhist and atheist school?

Tags: gods, brahman, adi-shankaracharya

Did Adi Shankaracharya give any argument to prove the existence of a perfect God (Brahman) against Buddhist and other atheist schools.

I am not asking argument for Monism, or about only God exists, but the argument for God itself.

Comment: Weird to call God perfect. He just is the way he is.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa well, by perfect I mean an all powerful, eternal, all Knowingly God. Buddhists believe in God but their God isn't all powerful and all knowing.